# PHP file download not working in Linux

Tags: php

I am using the below code to download mp3 files from server. The code is working fine in my local system(Windows OS).

However, when I am moving the code to server(Linux), I am getting a file not found error. I am sure that the file paths are correct and file is readable

```
if ($fd = fopen ($filePath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($filePath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($filePath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {                 
        case "mp3":                 
        header("Content-type: audio/mpeg"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$originalFileName."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
        break;
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$originalFileName."\"");
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd)
```

Comment: I've been through something like this and the problem was with the file names, If I'm not wrong, Linux is case sensitive with file extensions so you try to access the file `bla.JPG` is totally different from `bla.jpg`, check this

Comment: Where do you get error , fopen failed?

Comment: also there may be some problems with file permissions. check under what user httpd runs and what pemissions are assigned/owner to file you're trying to download

Comment: I have verified the file permission and it is 777. so i think all users can read it.also there is no issues with file name . it is small letters.

Comment: looks like the problem is with this line  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$originalFileName."\"");

Comment: Yes, that line wil be wrong. Change to header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .$originalFileName.'"'); Does that mean it's now working?

Comment: No Robbie, it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write that code:

```
// A couple of sanity checks on the file path, return a meaningful error message for debugging
if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
  exit('The requested file was not found');
} else if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  exit('The requested file is not accessible');
}

// Get the content type from the extension
// Consider using finfo instead: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php
$contentTypes = array(
  'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',
  'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
  'gif' => 'image/gif'
  // etc etc
);
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$contentType = (isset($contentTypes[$ext])) ? $contentTypes[$ext] : 'application/octet-stream';

// Content-* headers
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filePath));
header("Content-Type: {$contentType}");
// You will always want the same Content-Disposition: header, regardless of file type
// The only time you would need a different one is if you want to serve "inline" content
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$originalFileName}\"");

// No-Cache headers
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

// We don't want the script to time out on large files
set_time_limit(0);

// Output the file
readfile($filePath);
exit;
```

Comment: Hi Dave, The code which you have give above is also not working always. It also behaves like the same code which i have pasted in the original question. The strange think is sometimes for some files download is working and for some others it is not working. Is there any relation with file size limit? mine is 6mb

Comment: ok. dont know where it is failing. But below is the error message i am getting in firefox.

---------------------------------------------------------
File not found
 
        
 Firefox can't find the file at http://site.com/dm/d/o/dd6146c0f2c9b9e2a424a40cfa50d362/oi/yJY/JWiuvWN0jeRZVsAR00p/4dXang3A67r9ffuUO8g=/auth/900f12126fc0efcc896b6ae7c829c91f/.
       

  Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
  Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

-------------------------------------------------------

Comment: In code above, try changing `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');` near the top to `header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');` and see if the message changes